# Fedora15/Gnome3 - Exit elevated priviliges mode

Tags: fedora, security, users, gnome3

While using Fedora 14 (Gnome2), Each time if I was doing some privileged task (ex - mounting a new hard drive), I would be prompted for password and then there would appear an icon (like keys) on the taskbar. By clicking on it, I could exit the elevated priviliges mode.

I do not see any such feature - to exit priviliged mode - in F15/G3.

Is it possible to do so? How?

Comment: If you are running privileged tasks in a terminal, doesn't exit solve your problem?

Comment: @RoryAlsop I am talking about GUI (GNOME3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fedora15/Gnome 3 when you execute a command which requires elevated privileges, those privileges will remain until the window that required them is closed or until the privilege timeout is reached.

I think this was actually fixed just at the end of Gnome2.

Worth testing to see how long you retain privileges for.

Comment: In GNOME2, one could explicitly close elevated priviliges by clicking on an icon (like password keys) next to the clock.

Comment: I know - they decided it wasn't that useful. There was a bug report raised on that one